# Auto Resize embedded videos player

Tags: functions, video-player

Hi I am importing videos through xml feed - But from one source, the video player is too wide and the sidebar ads overlap it. The code I found on the single.php is

```
<div class="video_player">  
<?php if(get_option('amn_videos') !=""){ 
        $video = get_post_meta($post->ID, get_option('amn_videos') ,true); if(!empty($video)) {
            echo resizeEmbedded($video); 
        }}else{
            echo remove_unwanted_tag__(resizeEmbedded(the_content()));

    }
    ?> 
</div>
```

In functions.php I found this
//resizes embedded video html code to a specified width and height

```
function resizeEmbedded($subject) {
    $subject = preg_replace('/(width|height)(=|:)("|\'|)([\d]+)("|\'|)/', '${1}${2}${3}100%${3}', $subject);
    return $subject;
}
```

Now I don't know how to specify the width and height of the player, i tried tweaking 100% to 80% on the functions file but there is no effect. Is there a way to resize the videos through this code or use another code ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a max width to the container using CSS.

```
.video_player {
max-width: 800px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: It works like magic. This thought never crossed My mind. Thanks a lot.